# Ember routing for many and for just 1 item

Tags: ember.js, ember-router

How can I have a route that gives me all the foo items and will also give me a particular one?

eg I want this:

```
 this.resource('foos');//for all
 this.resource('foos', {path: ' foos/foo_id'}); // for one
```

Answer (score 2):

Here is a working fiddle for this example, http://jsfiddle.net/egft2ose/26/

The correct way of writing router will be,

```
App.Router.map(function () {
    this.resource('foos', {'path' : '/foos/'}, function() {
        this.route('index',{'path' : ''});    /* Routes to foos/ */
        this.route('foo',{'path' : '/:foo_id'}); /* Routes to foos/foo_id */
    });
});
App.IndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    redirect : function() {
        this.transitionTo('foos');
    }
});

App.FoosIndexRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function () {
        return ['Pune', 'Mumbai', 'New Delhi', 'Bengaluru'];
    }
});

App.FoosFooRoute = Ember.Route.extend({
    model : function(params) {
        return params.foo_id;
    }
});
```

Comment: thanks Sareskaph, I find that if I use the parent as **this.resource('foos'..** then I can no longer link to it as navitageToRoute('app.foos'), unless it is declared as a **this.route('foos')**